# Yii, relation model filter search

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am battling with CGridView filtering using the related model column, I have two models Cars and Colour, so Colour **has_many** Car and Car **belongs_to** Colour. The grid column from related model displays fine, I'm just not able to filter with it. I am getting mysql error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'carName'
```

**Colour model** HAS_MANY - Cars

I declaired the variable $carName from the Car model, so this model can see it.

```
public $carName;
public function rules()
{
   return array(
          array('id, carName, colourName', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
               )
}
public function relations()
{

    return array(
                'CarsObj'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Cars', 'colourID')
    );
}

public function search()
{ 

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = "CarsObj";
    $criteria->compare('carName', $this->carName, true);

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('colourName',$this->colourName,true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

**Car Model** BELONGS_TO - Colour

```
public function relations()
{ 
 return array( 
   'ColourObj'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Colour', 'colourID')
 );
}
```

CGridView, i am using the Colour Model search as my dataProvider

```
 $model = new Colour('search');
 $data = $model->search(); 
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
           'dataProvider'=>$data
           ,'filter'=>$model 
           ,'pager'=>array('header'=>'')  
           ,'columns'=>array( //related model column
                    'id',
                     'colourName',
                      array(
                            'header' => 'carName',
                            'type' => 'raw', 
                            'name' => 'carName',
                            'value' => function($data, $row) { //$data is item of DataProvider, $row is number of row (starts from 0)
                                $carNames= CHtml::listData((array)$data->ColourObj, 'id', 'carName');
                                return implode(', ', $carNames);
                            }
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default CActiveRecord using lazy load. You need to set attribute [together](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail) true. Also it's a good practice to set table alias when you using `with`.

```
public function search(){ 
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->with = 'CarsObj';
    $criteria->compare('CarsObj.carName',$this->carName,true);
    $criteria->compare('t.id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('t.colourName',$this->colourName,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Great!!, this solve my problem, Thanks alot @SiZE. This made my day, It was giving me a headache already

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public function search()
{

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = "CarsObj";
$criteria->compare('CarsObj.carName', $this->carName, true);

$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('colourName',$this->colourName,true);


return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```

}

Comment: I have tried both 

`$criteria->compare('CarsObj.carName', $this->carName, true);` and
`$criteria->compare('carName', $this->carName, true);`

I get same error, no difference